# Magento Order Email Notification not sent to admin sometimes

Tags: order-email, send-mail

I used magento application. Here sometimes order email sent to admin sometimes and sometimes not sending. I want to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since Magento 1.9.1.x, Magento transactional emails (orders, invoices...) are being sent by queue.

And this queue process is handled by cronjob. You have to make sure that your cronjob is up and running.

For your information: http://support.xtento.com/wiki/Setting_up_the_Magento_cronjob

Hope it helps.

Comment: @nithya Please consider to mark it as an answer if it solved your problem. Avoid to use comment like 'thanks' because it against Stackoverflow rules :)